# Need block content for each menu items

Tags: 6, routes

I need to have a separate block for a each menu items in my menu (Add item section).Is there any drupal module can help me or i should write the custom module.Please suggest the possible ways to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no module you can use with your situation. 
Possible way.

1. Create separate menu and place them in each block.

Please describe your scenario so that we can discuss more.

Comment: I have jquery menu, when the user mouse over on the menu items, it will show a block on the right side of the menu.

Comment: What you mean by block ?

Comment: jquery menu is to transform your multilevel menus into click and expand menus.

Comment: Block means a set of html content which will display when the user mouse over the corresponding menu item.